# Get an overall score for an array of weighted values

Tags: php

I have an array of scores and each score is weighted for importance. I would like to get an overall score out of 100 depending on the score and the weight giving to each item.

```
$array_one = array(
            array(
                'score' => 1.23,
                'max' => 10,
                'weight' => 10
            ),
            array(
                'score' => 56.78,
                'max' => 100,
                'weight' => 20
            ),
            array(
                'score' => 7.56,
                'max' => 10,
                'weight' => 20
            ),
            array(
                'score' => 4.67,
                'max' => 10,
                'weight' => 30
            )
        );
```

So if an item has a larger weight, it is giving a bigger percentage in the score out of 100. i.e if I get 4 scores equaling 50% of the max value in the range, but they all increase in weight 10,20,30,40, the second score has 10% more weight than the first, the third 20% more weight than the first, and the 4th 30% more weight than the first and so on. Also, some weights will be the same 10,20,20,30 or 10,10,10,10 etc. I hope this makes sense. So in summary each items score should be a percentage of the max value, then scores are weighted against 100. Expected results should return one overall score for all 4 items.

Comment: So you want to order the array by score and weight or what is the purpose?

Comment: so how does weighting work? are you saying that you take their weight's percentage of their score and add it to the 'total'?

Comment: no, not order. I want a overall score out of 100 or percentage.

Comment: What do you mean by `one overall score for all 4 items.` ??? Can you add your expected output of your current array

Comment: sum the scores. if there was no weighting, item 1 would have 25% of the total score, item 2 would have 25% etc. But the weighting gives more importance to item 4, so it gets a higher percentage.

Comment: so if the first three scores are zero, item 4 get 37.5% of overall score.

Comment: I wish you would respond that you understand. I thought it was more concise this time, and the voted down is making me paranoid. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum the scores divided by max multiplied by their weight. Take the sum of weights and divide by your max score (100). Then, divide the first number by the second number. This will be the total weighted score mapped to the [0, 100] range.